# Cannot write in docker image

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, permission-denied

I trying to execute some shell script in a docker image but I'm finding a blocker that cannot write files in the image.

```
/home/ws/my_Script.sh: line 25:
my_file.txt: Permission denied
```

That line in the script does the following:

```
# Store data in file
echo "${my_data}" > my_file.txt
```

My dockerfile has apparently well defined the permissions:

```
RUN groupadd -g 1001 ws \
    && useradd -r -u 1001 -g ws ws \
    && chown ws:ws -R /home/ws
USER ws
```

What I am missing? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just with what you've shown, the directory is owned by a user `ws` but your process is running as a different user `bpg`.  Should these match?  Are you running the container with a bind-mounted host directory, which will potentially have different ownership again?

Comment: my fault! but no, user is also ws

Comment: Your error message indicates you are running a script (``my_Script.sh``) and that is trying to modify the file ``my_file.txt``. While you may be setting the right user, permissions, etc. we cannot see what has happened between the setting and the execution of the script. Knowing that might help. Alternatively, either immediately before executing the script or inside the script echo some output such as the result of the ``whoami`` command and ``ls -al <dir>`` to check your assumptions about what you *think* is set against what is actually *set*.

Comment: What's the current directory when executing the script? Does the user have write permissions to that directory?